# OBIEE Catalog Manager - Determine which DASHBOARDS utilize particular reports

Tags: oracle11g, catalog, obiee

I've recently been using the Oracle Catalog Manager to create lineage reports to determine which analyses use particular columns. I haven't found a way, however, to determine which reports are used on particular dashboards. So if I wanted to delete a report, is there a way to determine which dashboards would be affected?

I know that when I migrate a dashboard page from the development environment to the test environment that the structure is preserved, so this information must be saved somewhere. However, when I try to create a report in the "_portal" folder that contains the dashboards, the report is always blank.

I was using [this](https://shivabizint.wordpress.com/tag/rpd-column-usage-in-reports/) page as an initial reference, but it only discusses how to find the reports that would be affected should a column be deleted from the rpd.

Part of what I'm trying to do is a clean-up to locate reports that aren't being used on any dashboards, but I also want to be able to better track which reports are being used and on which dashboards.

Answer (score 3):

The **Create Report** function will build a report of Dashboard/Analysis relationships.

[image]

[image]

Regarding moving/copying dashboards, it will not move all the dependent objects automatically - you will need to structure your Presentation Catalog such that you can migrate folders of objects as required.

Comment: I've tried connecting to the catalog in offline and online mode and through putty on the machine itself just to see if there were any differences, but the 'Available Columns' for me differ from the list in your picture. I'm lacking 'Dashboard Page Name' and 'Analysis Name' from the Available Columns when I choose to report on Dashboard. I do see 'Dashboard Page' and 'Analysis' listed under 'Select Children Type to Report on', but I don't have any way to alter those, nor do they show up in the resulting csv.

Comment: What patch version of OBIEE are you on? There were some changes to cat man between 11.1.1.7.1 patch sets.

Comment: We're using 11.1.1.7.140225 (Build 140209.2017 64-bit). Which version were the screenshots you provided from?

Comment: Ah, this was on 11.1.1.7.140114. I think in the newer version you can still get the data out, you'll just have to do it in two stages to get the dashboard -> dashboard page, page -> analysis (I don't have an env to hand so can't check the actuals).

Answer (score 1):

*OBIEE Catalog Manager Report* lacks the ability to extract data as

- Dashboard,
- Dashboard Page,
- Dashboard Prompt,
- Analysis

in a single row of data

We can have two combinations

1. Dashboard, Dashboard Page OR
2. Dashboard, Dashboard Prompt, Analysis

The OBIEE usage table does store the 4 fields in a single row.